# Having Textmate warn me when writing to a file that was modified since Textmate last read it

Tags: macos, textmate

Scenario:

I open a file, I edit it. After I began editing, the file is modified by another program. Finally, I save the file.

In that case, Vim would provide that helpful warning:

> WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it
>
> Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?

But Textmate will overwrite the file silently, which can result in unpleasant data loss (in my case, a *de facto* revert on Git). How can I prevent that?

Comment: You should try adding this question on Superuser.com it's much better suited to these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix: change focus to another application before clicking save, if you expect this behavior to happen often on a particular file. If you change focus and come back, TextMate will detect the change.

Not sure why you have programs modifying files while you're working on them, but...there you have it.